# How can I view the JDO Database?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jdo

Is there any way to look at the JDO database that I created using eclipse? Does Google provide any url where I can view them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver):

> The development web server includes a console web application. With the console you can browse the local datastore.
>
> To access the console, visit the URL /_ah/admin on your server: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin`

JDO in this case is only a wrapper to the Datastore API, so what you'll see is not a relational database.

Comment: Similarly the [AppEngine Console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/) includes a Datastore Viewer on the production environment.